# snowflake substring by pattern

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a string column in my table as below:

```
  accountNumber:123456
 {"accountNumber":"123456"}
```

i need a dynamic way of only extracting 123456 from these string. Can you plz suggest a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [the `REGEXP_SUBSTR(…)` built-in function](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regexp_substr.html) to extract substrings using a regular expression pattern.

If there will only be one number in each column value, a [number pattern](https://regexone.com/lesson/letters_and_digits) or a [numeric characters range](https://regexone.com/lesson/character_ranges) syntax will suffice:

```sql
SELECT
'accountNumber:123456' i1,
regexp_substr(i1, '[0-9]+') r1,
'{"accountNumber":"123456"}' i2,
regexp_substr(i2, '[0-9]+') r2;

+----------------------+--------+----------------------------+--------+         
| I1                   | R1     | I2                         | R2     |
|----------------------+--------+----------------------------+--------|
| accountNumber:123456 | 123456 | {"accountNumber":"123456"} | 123456 |
+----------------------+--------+----------------------------+--------+
```

If the number will be exactly 6 digits wide, use the [`{n}` repetition syntax](https://regexone.com/lesson/repeating_characters):

```
select
'accountNumber:123456,anotherNumber:123' i1,
regexp_substr(i1, '[0-9]{6}') r1,
'{"accountNumber":"123456", "anotherNumber": 123}' i2,
regexp_substr(i2,'[0-9]{6}') r2;

+----------------------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------+--------+
| I1                                     | R1     | I2                                               | R2     |
|----------------------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------+--------|
| accountNumber:123456,anotherNumber:123 | 123456 | {"accountNumber":"123456", "anotherNumber": 123} | 123456 |
+----------------------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------+--------+
```

If the number must only follow the text `accountNumber`, you can introduce [(capture groups)](https://regexone.com/lesson/capturing_groups):

```
select
'accountNumber:123456,anotherNumber:123,somethingElse:456789' i1,
regexp_substr(i1, 'accountNumber[:" ]+([0-9]{6})', 1, 1, 'e', 1) r1,
'{"accountNumber":"123456", "anotherNumber": 123, "somethingElse": 456789}' i2,
regexp_substr(i2, 'accountNumber[:" ]+([0-9]{6})', 1, 1, 'e', 1) r2;

+-------------------------------------------------------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
| I1                                                          | R1     | I2                                                                        | R2     |
|-------------------------------------------------------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------|
| accountNumber:123456,anotherNumber:123,somethingElse:456789 | 123456 | {"accountNumber":"123456", "anotherNumber": 123, "somethingElse": 456789} | 123456 |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
```

Building a fully correct regular expression will require more knowledge about all of the variances possible in the data. Try building out your patterns interactively with a good test-set on sites such as [Regex101](https://regex101.com/), [RegExr](https://regexr.com/), etc. that make it easier to develop them.

**Note**: If your data is actually in a JSON format throughout, Snowflake permits [parsing them into a `VARIANT` data type](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/parse_json.html) to [query them more naturally](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-semistructured.html):

```
select
parse_json('{"accountNumber":"123456", "anotherNumber": 123, "somethingElse": 456789}'):accountNumber::integer account_number;

+----------------+                                                              
| ACCOUNT_NUMBER |
|----------------|
|         123456 |
+----------------+
```